# jquery how to add new div before the THIS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i add new div before the btn?

I tried this:

```
element.parent("div").append(data);
```

But it add te new data after the button and i want it above it (and after the rest ot the divs)

```
<div>

  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>

  <a href="#" class="new_sec-btn" data-itinID="2">New Section</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) function to insert element in the set of matched elements before the target.

```js
$('.new_sec-btn').on('click', function(){
  data = `<div>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>`;

  $( data ).insertBefore( ".new_sec-btn" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>

  <a href="#" class="new_sec-btn" data-itinID="2">New Section</a>
</div>
```